# Laravel - upload bigger image

Tags: image, laravel, upload

i try to upload image but when upload bigger image (126KB, 300KB) i got error

```
 Internal Server Error
  The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was 
  unable to complete your request.

  Please contact the server administrator at 
  webmaster@xxxx to inform them of the time this 
  error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

  More information about this error may be available in the server error 
  log.

  Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while 
  trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I can upload smaller image (34KB, 78KB) but bigger i can't.
PLese help. Any idea?

Comment: Those file sizes should not be bigger than the default PHP file upload limit. `More information about this error may be available in the server error log`, is there any log available?

Comment: You might also want to check the PHP [file upload limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2184541/351330).

Comment: I check PHP file upload limit,  upload_max_filesize = 64M

Comment: Check also `post_max_size`

Comment: I check, but steel same :(

Comment: Which OS do you use? Windows or some other?